# translucent selected item in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I'm looking to add to a UIPicker the translucent grey / blue selection bar.  Currently it's not showing up:

http://screencast.com/t/XvSqotIPXYJD

Here's a screenshot of the way it should look:

http://www.screencast.com/users/jeffbubblet/folders/Jing/media/83a7c3d4-3f29-4e03-beb6-cf1118c9d91d

Right now I'm using the delegate method pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent.  I'd prefer not to have to use pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: unnecessarily if it can be avoided.

I can't seem to find anything in the docs about it, and I'm not looking to customize it one bit - just want the default behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

u would need to set the

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsSelectionIndicator
```

of your pickerview